# Winforms preferences values

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I'm a beginner in winforms, and just starting using it's preferences.

So, I add in my Settings.settings a Value named `path`, as string and User Scope.

I change it when I choose a new  path with a `FolderBrowserDialog` and then, after a click on a Ok button, i change the preferences like this :

```
private void buttonPref_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 subForm2 = new Form2(textBoxRep.Text);
            subForm2.ShowDialog();

            if (subForm2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Settings.Default.path= subForm2.rep();
                subForm2.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                subForm2.Close();
            }
         }

            public string rep()
            {
                return textBoxRep.Text;
            }
```

Then, when I run my Application, I load the value in my preferences :

```
    textBoxRep.Text = Settings.Default.path;
```

But, the value is set to empty after every new run.

So I tried with a Application Scope, but I got a read Only error on this : `Settings.Default.path`

How can I fix this? Is there a way to register the settings after mofified them?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling Settings.Default.Save() anywhere to save the setting into the config file?

Comment: Also worth noting that if you are running in VS, each time you re-run the application the config file tends to get written over.

Comment: Thank you for this precisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call Save method as below

```
Settings.Default.path= subForm2.rep();

Settings.Default.Save();
```

> Settings that are application-scoped are read-only, and can only be
>   changed at design time or by altering the .config file in between
>   application sessions. Settings that are user-scoped, however, can be
>   written at run time just as you would change any property value. The
>   new value persists for the duration of the application session. **You
>   can persist the changes to the settings between application sessions
>   by calling the Save method.**

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Complete answer. Strangely, when I tried at first, the .Save() does not appeared. But after reopen Visual studio, there it is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also call [`Settings.Default.Save();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx)